# How to remove "Trending searches" in Windows 10 search?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

In Windows 10, this is how my search looks:

[image]

How to remove the "Trending searches"? It is annoying.

I'm using 22H2 version of Windows 10.

Comment: Right-click on the taskbar, click Search. Uncheck Show search highlights.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio nah. It's already off.

Answer (score 16):

none of these answers worked for me but this one: https://winaero.com/disable-web-search-in-windows-10-taskbar/

1. open **registry editor** (*type regedit on the search box then hit enter*)
2. navigate to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows**
3. create **"Explorer"** under "Windows" (*right click "Windows" -> new -> Key*)
4. create DWORD value under "Explorer" called **"DisableSearchBoxSuggestions"** (*right click "Explorer" -> new -> **DWORD (32 bit) Value***)
5. assign value of **1** to this newly created value (*double click "DisableSearchBoxSuggestions" then type 1 in the "value data:" box. make sure **Hexadecimal** is selected and click "OK"*)

restart the PC and now annoying trending search section is gone!

Comment: This worked fine for me, Win 10 22H2, Feb 2023. It also removed "Microsoft Rewards" medal icon aside my account in the search bar though (not a problem for me).

Comment: Not a problem for my use case but this fully disables searching the web from the search bar. Thank god though because I hate edge

Comment: Too bad my corporate GPO won't let me add that new key. :(

Comment: 1. Worked perfectly.
2. Didn't have to scroll through dozens of confusing and contradictory threads (which was what I got from a Microsoft answer to this question).

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In previous windows versions, disabling web results from search did the trick.
I cannot test it on Win22H2, but it's worth a try.
This will of course turn off the web search results when you're searching for something in the menu as well.

I prefer the registry way of doing this. **It might require a restart of your computer**:

1 - navigate to

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
```

2 - Set dword value to 0 to disable web search (or set to 1 to enable):

```
BingSearchEnabled: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found no way to turn off the trending search that shows in the search box. Turning off "Show search highlights" does *not* remove it on my computer. I have toggled it several times rebooted in between and trending searches is always there.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT there is no way to disable it within the options. I've been trying to remove it myself, I find it extremely annoying/distracting

Comment: This is just a false answer, `Show search highlights` disables the behavior the author asked about, I verified it myself.

Comment: @Ramhound Turning off "Show search highlights" didn't disable "Trending searches" for me.

Comment: It did for me 21H2 here…

Comment: I'm specifically referring to the "Trending Searches" feature; search highlights as far as I can see is just to turn off the event specific highlights, like when there is a sports tournament or a holiday ‍♂️ But wouldn't surprise me if this behavior varied between versions.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using 22H2.

Comment: Your question fails to indicate that fact. If i knew that 10 days ago I would have researched the question differently 10 days ago

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry.