# Windows 11 Windows-S window: turn off distracting news?

Tags: windows, windows-11

When I hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> followed by say "cal" to launch calculator or what have you, there's always "news" that distracts me from my task at hand.  I literally reflexively shut my eyes while typing so that I don't see that thing.

How can I turn off the "news" display, and further hopefully turn off the "internet search" functionality which is never what I want?

Google is suggesting this window might be Cortana, whatever that is, but `Settings->Apps->Apps&features->Cortana->Advanced` Options shows it's off.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1751366/how-to-remove-trending-searches-in-windows-10-search) should be applicable. [DisableSearchBoxSuggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update/1325836#1325836) is also applicable